# Oracle Apex: Dynamic Link from table field with Substitution String - how to?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Interactive Report Page on Apex 5.1.4. I want to have a column consisting of links to a html-document, every record pointing to another anchor within that html. Something like http://document.html#table1 for record one and http://document.html#table2 for record 2 and so on.

On this behalf I have created a column named "URL" in the table the report is based on. This column holds references to the document like so:

```
#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#document.html#table10
```

So the html-document is a static workspace file within the applications shared components.

So there's one column in the report being defined as a link, link target is a URL wih the contents of column "URL".

[image: URL-column]

Problem: the substitution string #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# is not substituted. The resulting links look like this:

```
http://192.168.1.161:8080/apex/f?p=104:80:9943010919868::NO:::#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#document.html#table20
```

But the link really should look like this:

```
http://192.168.1.161:8080/apex/r/gut/files/static/v2/document.html#table20
```

Any ideas how to geht this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have it - thanks to Koen Loestrie for the helpful suggestion.

In the URL-field of the table I only store the name of the document and the anchor:

```
document.html#table1
```

The link definition has to be changed like so:
[image: link definition]

Then the links are built correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try `&WORKSPACE_IMAGES.document.html#table10` instead of using the "#" syntax

Comment: This resolves to `http://192.168.1.161:8080/apex/&WORKSPACE_IMAGES.document.html`